# Am I misunderstanding something about using the List and Fetch combination?

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to understand the combination of List and Fetch processors.

I have a directory with three JSON files and I get the ListAzureDataLakeStorage to list them. But when I connect a FetchAzureDataLakeStorage with which I intend to take only one of the files, the Fetch takes the same file three times. In summary, it takes the file whose azure.filename matches with the value that I put in the File Name property, but as many times as there are files in the listed directory.

I really want to use a single List and connect three Fetches to it, each one to take a different file, and thus use them for different streams.

In each Fetch I put in the "File Name" property the name of the file that I want to take. For example:

File Name: fileName1.json

I have also tried putting in "File Name" with Expression Language the following:

FileName: $ {azure.filename: equals ('fileName1.json')}. But this option causes a 404 empty body error.

But there is no way. Am I misunderstanding something about using the List and Fetch combination?

Answer (score 0):

If you are statically entering file names and you want to respond to each one differently, then the ListX processors aren't very beneficial to your flow.

The easier option would be to use a GenerateFlowFile processor with the appropriate schedule to trigger a corresponding FetchX processor.

If you're only doing this for 3 files, it's not too much manual overhead. You could also achieve something similar using RouteOnContent/Attribute.

Comment: Something similar is discussed here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Fetching-file-using-FetchAzureBlobStorage-Nifi-1-7/td-p/235561